# how to disable a button's onClick() event for some time?

Tags: android

I'm using **android studio** and i want to make a button disable when clicked for say 2 seconds and make it enable automatically after 2 seconds. i don't know where to start from. Can someone give me the code for doing this?

Comment: The [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/) is fantastic.  I would take a look at it, give it a try yourself, and if you run into issues, post another question with an [MCVE] that outlines a **specific** problem you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code..

```
 mbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mbtn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            },2000);
            mbtn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: this code requires min API 26 version, mine is below that. Can you help with that?

Comment: i wrote the above mentioned code. it is showing following error: Handler is abstract cannot be instantiated.

Comment: check your import statement is this import android.os.Handler;

Comment: the error is gone but there is another problem. when i click the button it gets disabled but its not getting enabled after that much time. why is it behaving like that?